# Given a list of several of the same object, group and combine them based on field value

Tags: c#

Sorry for the incoherent title. I don't know how to concisely explain my problem, which is why I didn't really know how to look it up. I'll explain using an example...

Let's say I have a class:

```
public class cas
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int num { get; set; }
}
```

With that class, I make several objects and stick them into a list. For the sake of example, I will make 4:

```
var list = new List<cas>
{
    new cas { name = "firstname", num = 1 },
    new cas { name = "firstname", num = 2 },
    new cas { name = "lastname", num = 3 },
    new cas { name = "lastname", num = 4 }
};
```

Is there a way to take this List and combine any objects with the same name field?

So, the new list would be 1 object with:

```
 name = "firstname", num = 3,
 name = "lastname", num = 7
```

There's the obvious "long" way to do it, but it would be clunky and expensive (go through the list several times to find like-objects). I was wondering if I was missing any clean way of doing it. I intentionally made a simple example so that the answer would be a proof of concept rather than writing my code for me. My actual problem is more complex than this, but I can't figure out this one aspect of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Linq, you have a `GroupBy` Method and a `Select` Method:

```
list = list.GroupBy(x=> x.name)
           .Select(x=> new cas() { name = x.Key, num  = x.Sum(y=> y.num) }).ToList();
```

Or using Elegant query-syntax:

```
list = (from item in list
        group item by item.name into grouping
        select new cas()
        {
            name = grouping.Key,
            num = grouping.Sum(x => x.num)
        }).ToList();
```

Note that to use these methods, you have to add `using System.Linq` at the top of your source file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use linq, you would have to group them on `name` property and then sum on the `num` property of each group like:

```
var result = list.GroupBy(x=>x.name)
                 .Select(g=> new cas
                             {
                                name = g.Key,
                                num = g.Sum(x=>x.num)
                             });
```